# Angular 9 : NullInjectorError: No provider for CompilerFactory

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v9

Get the message when running the app in browser prod/aot mode. Below is my main-aot.ts

Uncaught NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CompilerFactory]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for CompilerFactory!

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
//import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './app/app.module.ngfactory';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

enableProdMode();

// tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
/*platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory).catch(err => {
    console.log('CANNOT LOAD AOT MODULE')
    console.dir(AppModuleNgFactory);
    console.error(err)
});*/
platformBrowser().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => {
    console.log('CANNOT LOAD AOT MODULE')
    console.dir(AppModule);
    console.error(err)
});
```

Comment: you should be bootstrapping ModuleNgFactory in AOT

Comment: Have you tried rerunning ``npm install``

Comment: @Andrei-- Angular 9/ivy does not produce NgFactory files.

Comment: @NathanToulbert - yes but how will it help in this case?

Comment: It might not (and obviously didn't in your case) but that is always my first step with issues like this. Analogous to shutting down or unplugging a computer that is slow or not working properly. It is a quick step that can't hurt as you are just reinstalling dependencies that were already installed. However, if something installed improperly or incompletely (which is sometimes the case with npm), it will save you a lot of time a d energy.

Answer (score 13):

I was getting this error because I was not running ```ngcc`` as now required with Angular 9 when Ivy is enabled. So to fix this I added the following to my package.json scripts:

```
"postinstall": "ngcc"
```

Then ran it:

```
npm run postinstall
```

Also, the following bootstrap code was sufficient, platformBrowserDynamic is not required with AOT enabled:

```
 platformBrowser().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

Comment: Saved my life :). Thank you so much :)

Comment: Just an FYI, with Angular 13, you shouldn't need to do this anymore. The view engine is gone so there's nothing that needs to be compiled anymore

Answer (score 1):

In angular 9 with ivy, there are no ngFactory files anymore, you no longer need main-aot.ts, only main.ts should be necessary

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently experienced a similar error : `NullInjectorError: No provider for CompilerFactory!` after on deploying my remote server. I had done an automated build which was building the `dist/` using `npm run build --prod` changing this to `ng build --prod` worked for me!

Kindly check that your environments are running / building the application using similar tools.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding `ngcc` to your `postinstall` script, you can try to delete `node_modules` or just delete the installed Angular libraries and run `npm install`. **This might also fix this issue.**

In my particular case what seemed to happen is that one of the dependencies is an Angular library, those get compiled into a folder in `node_modules`. After updating from Angular 10 to 11 that compilation was probably cached but should be recompiled.

So both running `ngcc` or deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling the dependencies seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** with Angular 13, the view engine is gone, and you will no longer need to run `ngcc`. It should just work.

Interestingly enough, the angular compatibility compiler (ngcc) will be ran behind-the-scenes when running the cli tools, but not when using the build tools directly.

This means you will probably find that when you are doing an `ng build` that it works fine. However, `ng run build` or just using the Angular's "architect" tool directly with some sort of build tool like Bazel, then you will need to run the `ngcc` command yourself.

@Parliaments postinstall trick should work. But just wanted to explain it more.